# Rails: Incorrect MySQL client library version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby/ RoR (like ... today new)

In trying my first real command:

> rails g controller welcome index

This error appears:

> .../lib/mysql2.rb:9: in 'require': Incorrect MySQL client library
>   version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.16 but the client library is
>   5.1.53 (RunTimeError).

Any step by step help on how to fix this would be most appreciated.

Some background:

- I did reinstall MySQL between installing RailsInstaller and running this, for other reasons.
- Win 7 x64, running 32 bit MySQL
- Ruby/Rails installed today from http://railsinstaller.org

Comment: I should add that if I run:   
`gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql=config="c:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.5/bin/mysql_config"`  
  
It barfs with:   
`ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.` and   
`could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libararies and/or headers`

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the development version of MySQL installed that has those libraries? And a C compiler installed?

It may be better to use the ruby native gem (if it still exists) for Windows. That's what we used to do in the Rails 2 days.

Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: See JohnF's comment here for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841406/cannot-install-mysql2-gem