# "undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: mysql, windows, ruby-on-rails-3

I am getting "undefined method `accept' for nil:NilClass" error while running db:migrate. My configuration is:

```
Rails 3.2.8
MySql 5.1.54
OS : win7
ruby : 1.9.2
```

my gems list command output:

```
F:\RailsApp\MyApp>gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.8)
actionpack (3.2.8)
activemodel (3.2.8, 3.1.0)
activerecord (3.2.8)
activeresource (3.2.8)
activesupport (3.2.8, 3.1.0)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1 x86-mingw32)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.1.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
json (1.7.4)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (1.6.0)
multi_json (1.3.6)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
mysql2 (0.3.11 x86-mingw32, 0.2.6 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1, 1.3.6)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.8)
railties (3.2.8)
rake (0.9.2.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.12, 2.5.8)
sass (3.2.0)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.1.3)
thor (0.15.4)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.7)
```

I have also copy the %MYSQLPATH%/bin/libmySQL.dll file to %RUBYHOME%/bin folder.

Can anybody pleas help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have resolve the problem with reference to this post [mysql2 gem compiled for wrong mysql client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library).

What I have done is as follows:

1. download and extract the package from http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick
2. remove all mysql/mysql2 gem and re-install mysql gem with this command:
   `gem install mysql --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir=E:/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32`
3. add `gem 'mysql'` in GemFile
4. modify database.yml with `adapter:mysql`
5. copy MYSQLHOME/bin/libmsql.dll to RUBYHOME/bin
6. if find dsl error then add `require 'rake/dsl_definition'` at top of RakeFile

and it works.. :-)

My final GemFile is:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'mysql'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be a AR-JDBC issue. Try running

```
bundle update activerecord-jdbc-adapter
```

This may help you..

If it didn't work for you, try with

```
bundle update mysql2
```

For more info look into the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4632)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue fixed by correcting database.yml file.  It was having adopter as mysql2 now I have correct it to mysql