# Can't get MYSQL to run with Ruby on Rails on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql2 gem compiled for wrong mysql client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library)

Here's the error I keep getting:

```
C:\Sites\ProjectName>rails s
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.
rb:2:in `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled
 for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.5.28. (RuntimeError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/m
ysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/m
ysql2.rb:9:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/m
ysql2.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:68:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:66:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:66:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler/runti
me.rb:55:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.2.1/lib/bundler.rb:12
8:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/ProjectName/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `tap'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/comman
ds.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I know it says the error in my face unfortunately I have no idea how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [mysql2 gem compiled for wrong mysql client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library)

There's a full explanation of what's happening, and suggestions for how to fix the problem.