# gem bundler error Could not find gem 'myql2 (~> 0.3.11) x86-mingw32' on Window 7 64 bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, mysql2

I am using ruby 1.9.3 with rails 3.2.12 on Windows 7 64 bit and getting following error and having problem to install mysql2 gem.

```
gem install mysql2

I am getting following error
  You've installed the binary version of mysql.
  It was built using MySQL Connector/C version 6.0.2.
  It's recommended to use the exact same version to avoid potential issues.

  At the time of building this gem, the necessary DLL files where available
  in the following URL:

  http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick

  You can put the lib\libmysql.dll available in this package to your Ruby bin directory.
  E.g. C:\Ruby\bin
```

I following dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick and copied as instructed but no luck.

I also follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library) but getting same error at the end
any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you using cygwin?

Comment: no just windows console

Comment: I think you would be better off using cygwin if you want to program in Windows. Otherwise I would recommend switching to Linux or Mac for Ruby Programming.