# Latest versions of mysql2 and mysql gems requires mysql 6.0. How to use it with 5.x?

Tags: mysql, ruby, windows

I've got a clean install of Ruby+Gems+DevKit+Rails. I've installed both mysql and mysql2. When i'm trying to start a development server i've got an error:

```
C:/Ruby/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.6.10. (RuntimeError)
```

How can i use 5.6.10 version of MySQL?
I'm running it on a Windows platform.

Comment: funny, i thought i was using mysql2 against mysql5

Comment: It exits with error about not being 6.0. I'm trying to reinstall everything right now.

Comment: Well, latest versions of mysql and mysql2 is not compatible with mysql 5.x. How are you using it?

Comment: gem list .....  mysql2 (0.3.11)     against mysql   Server version: 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Comment: Maybe Windows version of this gems was compiled in a strange way...

Comment: on my windows box i have   gem list ... mysql (2.8.2 x86-mingw32)

Comment: I've tried to use mysql: `C:/Ruby/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql-2.9.1-x86-mingw32/lib/mysql.rb:4:in require': Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 6.0.0 but the client library is 5.6.10. (RuntimeError)`

Comment: looks like you merely sucked down the wrong version

Comment: Same as:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the mysql2 and mysql gems is not to do with the mysql server version.

mysql2 was a rewrite of the mysql gem that was designed to be a more modern set of bindings to libmysql: proper support of ruby 1.9 encodings, better (and fast) typecasting and so on.

Comment: Well, mysql2 and mysql gems was compiled for 6.0 for some reason.