# rails 4 mysql2 gem Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.5.30 but the client library is 5.6.19

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mysql2

upon deployment in production, I get this error , I don't understand where is coming from this 5.5.30... but I uninstalled the gem locally (oSX) and remotely (Debian) and reinstalled it... so it should be compiled with the latest libraries.. 5.6.19

here are both MySQL versions installed ...

on Debian

```
         mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";'

        Enter password: 

        +-------------------------+-------------------+

        | Variable_name           | Value             |

        +-------------------------+-------------------+

        | innodb_version          | 5.6.19            |

        | protocol_version        | 10                |

        | slave_type_conversions  |                   |

        | version                 | 5.6.19-1~dotdeb.1 |

        | version_comment         | (Debian)          |

        | version_compile_machine | x86_64            |

        | version_compile_os      | debian-linux-gnu  |

        +-------------------------+-------------------+
```

on OSX

```
        yves$ mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";'

        Enter password: 

        +-------------------------+------------------------------+

        | Variable_name           | Value                        |

        +-------------------------+------------------------------+

        | innodb_version          | 5.6.19                       |

        | protocol_version        | 10                           |

        | slave_type_conversions  |                              |

        | version                 | 5.6.19                       |

        | version_comment         | MySQL Community Server (GPL) |

        | version_compile_machine | x86_64                       |

        | version_compile_os      | osx10.7                      |

        +-------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library ... any use?

Comment: I re-installed rbenv , ruby 2.1.2 and rails w mysql2, no mysql lib error anymore .. ( but other issues in deployment..)  thanks