# bundle install: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems, mysql2, bundle-install

i have git clone git://github.com/jalagrange/excel_test_app.git
I got the below error while the bundle install, This does not happen with other my applications.

following error

```
Installing mysql2 (0.3.6) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for main() in -llibmysql... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers. Check the mkmf.log file for more
details. You may need configuration options.
```

gemfile

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem "spreadsheet"
gem "carrierwave"
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'flash_cookie_session'
gem "pry"
gem "haml"
gem 'fog'

# To use Delayed_job
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

group :test do
  # Pretty printed test output
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end


group :development, :test do
  gem "mysql2", "0.3.6"
  gem "letter_opener"
  gem "pry"
end
```

this question and answer not working for my problem..
[gem install: Failed to build gem native extension (can't find header files)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304438/mysql-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

problem solved,
i have run bundle update..
thx all..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run the following command and install the bundle again

`sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev`

Comment: if still it doesn't work out, please see the accepted answer of this thread, it's the very similar problem you're facing.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841406/cannot-install-mysql2-gem

Comment: I got the below error while the install gem install mysql2 -v=0.3.6 but no error gem install mysql2

Comment: i was getting error Installing mysql2 (x.x.x) with native extensions .... and install with option.. I have tried "sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev" and boom

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

then

```
gem install mysql2 -v=X.X.x
```

where x.x.x is the version that you need
then bundle install

Answer (score 0):

2018.11.05 => **Depreciated.**

After an `apt search libmysqlclient-dev` you will get the new package you will need to continue installing mysql2.

In my case it results **default-libmysqlclient-dev**

```
apt install default-libmysqlclient-dev

gem install mysql2 -v 0.4.6
```

=> then you can restart thebundle install`enter code here` cmd.