# Struggling to boot up WEBrick

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, webrick

First a little indication of what I'm running:

- Operating System: **Windows 8 64-bit**
- Ruby version: **1.9.3p362**
- Rails version: **3.2.11**

I've created a new rails project called `simple_cms` under `C:\Users\Dean\Documents\Ruby_Projects\` .

I then navigate into the project directory, so my path then is `C:\Users\Dean\Documents\Ruby_Projects\simple_cms\`

I then run (with my administrator command prompt)

> rails server

but I then get a whole lot of errors but the most prominent one being:

> The specified module could not be found some\path\mysql2\1.9\mysql2.so

Any ideas?

**EDIT: Attached is my full command prompt output...**

[image]

Comment: how did you install ruby, usually the best way to install ruby and rails on windows is to use the rubyinstaller

Comment: @Egryan - Yep I used the rubyinstaller...

Comment: @Egryan - Have a look at my edited post, attached is the full output of my command prmpt :)

Comment: I sorted it out, the answer can be found [here][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740868/mysql2-gem-compiled-for-wrong-mysql-client-library

Comment: Good to know, I would answer your own question so other people will get the benefit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `mysql2` gem hasn't been installed correctly.

Check out the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7534054/749004) for info on properly installing the `mysql2` gem. That should take care of the rest of your errors.